# Simple way to forward a no-value function parameter in CMake

Tags: cmake

I have two CMake functions (let's call them `inner` and `outer`) which use `cmake_parse_arguments` with the same option (no-value parameter) `XXX` and some other parameters, so they look like

```
function(inner)
    set(prefix ARG)
    set(noValues XXX)
    set(singleValues ...)
    set(multiValues ...)
    cmake_parse_arguments(${prefix}
                          "${noValues}"
                          "${singleValues}"
                          "${multiValues}"
                          ${ARGN})
...
endfunction()

function(outer)
    set(prefix ARG)
    set(noValues XXX)
    set(singleValues ...)
    set(multiValues ...)
    cmake_parse_arguments(${prefix}
                          "${noValues}"
                          "${singleValues}"
                          "${multiValues}"
                          ${ARGN})
...
    inner(
        $<$<BOOL:${ARG_XXX}>:XXX>
        ...)
endfunction()
```

The intention is that if `XXX` is set when calling `outer`, it will be passed through to `inner`. But this doesn't seem to work; if I add

```
# in outer
    message("in outer, FILE=${ARG_FILE}, XXX=${ARG_XXX}")

# in inner
    message("in outer, FILE=${ARG_FILE}, XXX=${ARG_XXX}")
```

(`FILE` is another argument getting passed through, but it's a mandatory single-value argument, so it's just `FILE "${ARG_FILE}` which works well) I see

```
in outer, FILE=abc.def, XXX=TRUE
in inner, FILE=abc.def, XXX=FALSE
```

Why doesn't this work as I expect and what is the correct way to do it?

Of course, I could do

```
if (ARG_XXX)
    inner(XXX ...all the other arguments...)
else()
    inner(...all the other arguments...)
endif()
```

but I'm hoping that's not necessary given the actual codebase doesn't just have 2 layers with 1 function each...

The CMake version is 3.15.5 but the answer must work on 3.10.2 and later.

Comment: That generator expression `$<$<BOOL:${ARG_XXX}>:XXX>` will be passed verbatim as (because it is unquoted, at _least_) one single argument. Generator expressions are only evaluated _after_ all CMake code has been processed

Comment: Will `inner` ever be called except by `outer?`. Or is it merely a private implementation detail of `outer`?

Comment: @AlexReinking That answers "Why doesn't this work" at least (and quoting doesn't help either).

Comment: @AlexReinking It's called by multiple functions `outer1`, `outer2`, etc. (and they are called by `even_further_out1`, etc.)

Comment: Do they _all_ accept `ARG_XXX` or only some of them?

Comment: I checked and it seems all relevant functions do (I could have missed some, the project is large).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The idea here is to use CMake's list-expanding parameter passing syntax. When you write `func(${args})` it will use the *elements* of the list `${args}` to construct a call to `func`. For example, if you have `set(args "1" "2" "3")`, then `func(${args})` is the same as `func("1" "2" "3")`, but if you *quote* the argument to `func` then this won't happen, i.e. `func("${args}") == func("1;2;3")`.

So in this case, we'll just convert your `TRUE` or `FALSE` variable `ARG_XXX` into a local variable `XXX` that is either just `XXX` or empty for true/false, respectively, and then call `inner(${XXX})`.

```
if (ARG_XXX)
    set(XXX XXX)
else ()
    set(XXX "")
endif ()

inner(${XXX})
```

As far as I know there is no better way. Here's a full demo:

```
# test.cmake
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.9)

function(inner)
    cmake_parse_arguments(ARG "XXX" "" "" ${ARGN})
    message(STATUS "inner: ARG_XXX = ${ARG_XXX}")
endfunction()

function(outer)
    cmake_parse_arguments(ARG "XXX" "" "" ${ARGN})

    message(STATUS "outer: ARG_XXX = ${ARG_XXX}")

    if (ARG_XXX)
        set(xxx XXX)
    else ()
        set(xxx "")
    endif ()

    inner(${xxx})
endfunction()

outer()
outer(XXX)
```

Run with `cmake -P test.cmake` and this will print:

```
$ ~/Downloads/cmake-3.9.6-Linux-x86_64/bin/cmake -P test.cmake
-- outer: ARG_XXX = FALSE
-- inner: ARG_XXX = FALSE
-- outer: ARG_XXX = TRUE
-- inner: ARG_XXX = TRUE
```

This will work *very* far back, but I had the Kitware-official statically-linked version 3.9 sitting in my `~/Downloads` folder, so I used that.

---

On the other hand, if *every caller* of `inner` already parses `ARG_XXX`, then you can use CMake's dynamic scoping rules to see if `ARG_XXX` was set in the caller. When you call a function, CMake *copies* the variable environment and passes it to the callee. So the following will work, too:

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.9)

function(inner)
    cmake_parse_arguments(ARG "" "" "" ${ARGN})
    message(STATUS "inner: ARG_XXX = ${ARG_XXX}")
endfunction()

function(outer)
    cmake_parse_arguments(ARG "XXX" "" "" ${ARGN})
    message(STATUS "outer: ARG_XXX = ${ARG_XXX}")

    inner()
endfunction()

outer()
outer(XXX)
```

In this case, `inner` relies on `outer` to parse the `XXX` option. Obviously this is fairly brittle if `inner` might be called by arbitrary functions (and having `ARG_XXX` set to something reasonable becomes a part of its contract).

Comment: I expect the second option wouldn't pass code review, but thank you for it anyway! I'll test the first one.

Comment: @AlexeyRomanov - fair enough, I just wanted to show you your options :)

Answer (score 1):

There is probably nothing to add to the [@alex-reinking answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/68874663/23715), except that if you have multiple such cases, then you may want to wrap the optional argument setting logic into a convenience macro, like this:

```
macro(set_if target condition)
  if(${condition})
    set(${target} "${target}")
  else()
    set(${target})
  endif()
endmacro()
```

The else clause is used to avoid warnings with `--warn-uninitialized` CMake flag.

The macro above may make the code more concise:

```
function(inner)
  set(options "XXX" "YYY" "ZZZ")
  cmake_parse_arguments(inner "${options}" "" "" ${ARGN})

  message(STATUS "Inner function: ${ARGN}")
  message(STATUS "XXX: ${inner_XXX}")
  message(STATUS "YYY: ${inner_YYY}")
  message(STATUS "ZZZ: ${inner_ZZZ}")
endfunction()

function(outer)
  set(options "XXX" "YYY" "ZZZ")
  cmake_parse_arguments(outer "${options}" "" "" ${ARGN})

  message(STATUS "Outer function: ${ARGN}")
  message(STATUS "XXX: ${outer_XXX}")
  message(STATUS "YYY: ${outer_YYY}")
  message(STATUS "ZZZ: ${outer_ZZZ}")

  set_if(XXX outer_XXX) # option arg to be passed
  set_if(YYY outer_YYY) # option arg to be passed
  set_if(ZZZ outer_ZZZ) # option arg to be passed

  inner(i0 ${XXX} i1 ${YYY} i2 ${ZZZ} i3)
endfunction()

outer(o0 XXX o1 YYY o2)
outer(o0 YYY o1 ZZZ o2)
outer(o0 XXX o1 YYY o2 ZZZ o3)
```

The output will be:

```
-- Outer function: o0;XXX;o1;YYY;o2
-- XXX: TRUE
-- YYY: TRUE
-- ZZZ: FALSE
-- Inner function: i0;XXX;i1;YYY;i2;i3
-- XXX: TRUE
-- YYY: TRUE
-- ZZZ: FALSE
-- Outer function: o0;YYY;o1;ZZZ;o2
-- XXX: FALSE
-- YYY: TRUE
-- ZZZ: TRUE
-- Inner function: i0;i1;YYY;i2;ZZZ;i3
-- XXX: FALSE
-- YYY: TRUE
-- ZZZ: TRUE
-- Outer function: o0;XXX;o1;YYY;o2;ZZZ;o3
-- XXX: TRUE
-- YYY: TRUE
-- ZZZ: TRUE
-- Inner function: i0;XXX;i1;YYY;i2;ZZZ;i3
-- XXX: TRUE
-- YYY: TRUE
-- ZZZ: TRUE
```